# Service account is missing in Google Developer Console

Tags: google-oauth

Google's documentation have a really simple howto on creating service account; two, actualy: [Google Accounts Authentication and Authorization](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#overview) and [Google Developers Console Help](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#serviceaccounts). But the problem is in step 5. b.: *When prompted, select **Service Account** and click **Create Client ID***.

There is no **Service Account** option. All I see is the following dialog:[image]

What is wrong? Why don't I see the **Service Account** option? And so, how can I create one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create this Client ID, when you have just "Can edit" permission. So, the solution is to log in with account which has owner permission.